# Is there a better way to implement count sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, optimization, counting-sort

The following code implements count sort: an algorithm that sorts in O(n) time complexity, but with a (possibly) heavy memory cost. Is there any better way to go about this?

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr = { 12,31,300,13,21,3,46,54,44,44,9,-1,0,-1,-1 };
    // find the minimum element in the list
    int min = arr.at(std::distance(arr.begin(), std::min_element(arr.begin(), arr.end())));
    // offset for negative values
    for (auto& elem : arr) {
        elem -= min;
    }
    // new max
    int max = arr.at(std::distance(arr.begin(), std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end())));
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec;
    vec.resize(max + 1);
    for (const auto& number : arr) {
        // handle duplicates
        if (!vec.at(number).second) {
            vec[number] = std::make_pair(number + min, 0);
        }
        vec.at(number).second++;
    }
    std::vector<int> sorted_vec;
    for (const auto& pair : vec) {
        if (pair.second) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pair.second; i++) {
                sorted_vec.push_back(pair.first);
            }
        }
    }
    std::for_each(sorted_vec.begin(), sorted_vec.end(), [](const int& elem) { 
        std::cout << elem << " "; 
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that there exists [`minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)

Comment: @Bob__, thanks, but will that change with the offset?

Comment: Well, you are offsetting *all* the elements by the *same* amount.

Comment: Why do you write retrieving the min/max element in such a weird way? You've got iterators to access the value with, no use to look up again `if (arr.empty()) { throw ...; } int min = *std::min_element(arr.begin(), arr.end()); int max = *std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());` or with bob's suggestion `auto [minIterator, maxIterator] = std::minmax_element(arr.begin(), arr.end()); int min = *minIterator; int max = *maxIterator;`

Comment: As for the actual question: Radix sort may be an option...

Comment: Also note that in this case, with a source size which is an order of magnitude less than the difference between the max and the min, `std::sort` is probably faster. Way faster.

Comment: As fabian and Bob_ points out, this sequence is not an ideal candidate for counting sort.

Comment: @fabian, sure, I can change the way I access the min and max but please note that the use of min and max is different. If I use minmax, my min will be correct which I might use as offset, but my max will be 300 instead of the required 301.

Comment: Although as @Bob__ suggested I might as well could've used offset on the max element...

Comment: @Bob__ *std::sort is probably faster. Way faster.* faster than O(n)?

Comment: "count sort: an algorithm that sorts in `O(n)` time complexity" Not when `n` is defined conventionally, as the size of the input. Your algorithm sorts `[1000000, 0]` in `O(1000000)` time, while `std::sort` would sort it in `O(2 log 2)`

Comment: Well, [yes](https://quick-bench.com/q/ROkYa3W1ut7NrinLPeqVXD-dixw), especially when you can avoid memory allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. with input A[0:n], max_element=k, min_element=0, for the counting sort:

- time complexity: **O(n + k)**
- space complexity: O(k)

You can NOT get O(n) time complexity, with O(1) space complexity.

If your **k** is very large, you should not use count sort algorithm.

2. In your code, you use std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> to store the count.
   It will get O(2*k) space complexity. You can just use a array of int.

Like this way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr = { 12,31,300,13,21,3,46,54,44,44,9,-1,0,-1,-1 };
    // find the minimum element in the list
    int min = *std::min_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    // offset for negative values
    for (auto& elem : arr) {
        elem -= min;
    }
    // new max
    int max = *std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    std::vector<int> vec(max + 1, 0);
    for (const auto& number : arr) {
        vec[number] += 1;
    }
    std::vector<int> sorted_vec;
    for (int num = 0; num < vec.size(); num++) {
        int count = vec[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            sorted_vec.push_back(num + min);
        }
    }
    std::for_each(sorted_vec.begin(), sorted_vec.end(), [](const int& elem) { 
        std::cout << elem << " "; 
    });
    return 0;
}
```